# Variable output hash function

Tags: hash

I know that there are hash functions that from a variable length input can give a fixed output. To take the simplest one, using the module of ten no matter how big is the input number I will always get an output between 0 and 9.

I need to do have from an unknown password, a variable length output. My first thought was to use the module, increasing the prim number as much as many digits I need to have as output.

My problems are:

- I must handle short passwords as well as I would with long passwords;
- I don't know how long should the output be before writing the program, and even though I would know after the user has set the password I may need to change it if he modifies the file.

My first thought was using a simple function and modify it based on my needs.

If I have to hash 123 but I need to have 5 characters as output, that's what I would do:

1. I add 2 zeros on the right, changing the input to 12300;
2. I take the lowest 5 digits prime number (10007);
3. And I then I have my hash doing 12300 % 10007 = 02293.

But since I would probably need output in the order of hundreds if not thousands I'm pretty sure module is not the solution to my problem.

I could also try to create my own hash function, but I have no idea how to verify if it works or if it's trash.

Are there some common solutions in literature for this kind of problem?

Comment: *"variable length output"* - is there any limit/range of output lengths you will require?  For example, if it's always going to be <=N bits, you can look for an existing hash function that's >= "N bit", or even assemble up to N bits from a combination of hashes, or applying the same hash to differently salted versions of the input.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions#Non-cryptographic_hash_functions) for some algos you might find and use.

Comment: Just to make sure there's not a fundamental misunderstanding here, if you want a value between say 0 and 9999, you can take a larger hash (e.g. a 16, 32 or 64 bit hash) and then apply `% 10000`.

Comment: I want to take as input the user password and then manipulate for various uses. For example I may want it to become a 256 bits long, or 512 or even 1024 depending on the situation. Let's pretending I have A (user password), B (some salting system) giving C as output. I could just do A * B = C, increasing B to get a bigger C, but I was loosing for something less trivial.